# Error in JSP taglib directive

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I receive the following error while deploying in weblogic:

> Parsing of JSP File '/pages/RegisteredEmployee.jsp' failed: /pages/RegisteredEmployee.jsp(5): Error in using tag library uri='/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld' prefix='html': The Tag class 'org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag' has no setter method corresponding to TLD declared attribute 'name', (JSP 1.1 spec, 5.4.1) probably occurred due to an error in /pages/RegisteredEmployee.jsp line 5: `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>`

My `struts-html.tld` is inside `/WEB-INF` folder. I also tried to change the tag lib directive path to `http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html`, it displayed same error. I also copied `struts-html.tld` into `/WEB-INF/lib`, it displayed same error.

How can I solve this problem?

`RegisteredEmployee.jsp`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%> 
<html:html>
  <html:form action="reg employee">
    <body>
      <center>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Employee Id:</td>
            <td><html:text property="id"/></td>
            <td><html:submit value="Login to see your details"></html:submit></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </body>
  </html:form>
</html:html>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/RegisteredEmployee.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be found here:

```
<html:submit value="Login to see your details"></html:submit>
```

I haven't done Struts in months, but it's complaining on `value="..."`. Rather do this,

```
<html:submit>Login to see your details</html:submit>
```

There's (probably) no attribute `value` on `<html:submit>`.